# Accessing Map Object in Nuxt-leaflet

Tags: leaflet, nuxt.js, vue2leaflet

I have an leaflet map like this (snipped):

```
<template>
<client-only>
  <div>
    <l-map
      ref="myMap"
      :zoom="zoom"
      :max-zoom="maxZoom"
      :min-zoom="minZoom"
      :crs="crs"
      :options="mapOptions"
```

Im trying to access my created map object of a leaflet map during mounted hook like this:

```
mounted() {
    this.maxZoom = this.$refs.myMap.mapObject.getMaxZoom()
```

or

```
this.$L.myMap.mapObject.getMaxZoom()
```

but i alwayways get a "... is undefine" error.
What am i doing wrong here and how can i access my map object to get some stuff like .getMaxZoom() during runtime using nuxt-leaflet? Without nuxt-leaflet, only using vue2leaflet it works like a charm...

Comment: Can you make a reproduction of your issue? Preferably on codesandbox.

Comment: @kissu i created a simplified codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-gauss-02wpx?file=/components/Map.vue 

But unfortunately i cant get it run to reproduce the issue cause some module build errors occur. If you get this sandbox run i guess my issue should be reproduced :(

Comment: could you try with this inside `mounter(){}` method: `this.$nextTick(() => { let map = this.$refs.myMap.mapObject; console.log(map); });` and see if you have any response ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Nuxt.

```
<client-only>
  <LMap
    ref="map"
    @hook:mounted="mapInitialization"

    :zoom="1"
    :center="[640, 512]"
    :options="{ attributionControl: false, zoomControl: false }"
    :crs="crs"
  >
    <LImageOverlay :url="url" :bounds="bounds"></LImageOverlay>
    <LMarker :lat-lng="[69.5, 177.5]" :z-index="1"></LMarker>
  </LMap>
</client-only>
```

```
methods: {
  mapInitialization() {
    const map = this.$refs.map
    console.log('MAP FROM STUFF', map)
    map.mapObject.setView()
  }
}
```

$nextTick in mounted method doesn't work for me properly, because it requires some tick and on the initialization of the page ref is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work with the latest version of [nuxt3-leaflet](https://nuxt.com/modules/nuxt3-leaflet):

```
<template>
  <div style="height:100vh; width:100vw">
    <LMap
      ref="map"
      :zoom="zoom"
      :max-zoom="18"
      :center="[47.21322, -1.559482]"
      @ready="mapInitialized"
    >
      <LTileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution="&amp;copy; <a href=&quot;https://www.openstreetmap.org/&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
        layer-type="base"
        name="OpenStreetMap"
      />
    </LMap>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const zoom = ref(6)

const map = ref(null)

// When the map is ready
const mapInitialized = () => {
  console.log('Map is ready')
  console.log(map.value.maxZoom)
}
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).